# Can Doctrine 1.2 handle custom data type like geometry data type?

Tags: doctrine, yaml

I want to create tables that contain geometry data types ([Mysql spatial extension](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-spatial-datatypes.html)). which steps are needed to map these with Doctrine 1.2?

Any idea how is the codes of yaml mapping and corresponding modal class for custom data mapping with Doctrine 1.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doctrine is just a mapper. You may model anything you want if your database supports it. But no guarantee this will be portable to all the databases supported by Doctrine.

For *basic* spatial analysis, there is a [Doctrine Locatable extension](http://trac.doctrine-project.org/browser/extensions/Locatable?rev=7461).

Comment: It seems that the extension just outputs the latitude and longitude automatically based on the location.http://trac.doctrine-project.org/browser/extensions/Locatable/branches/1.2-1.0/docs/en/usage.txt?rev=7461
It's not dealing with the geometry data types, e.g. the loading and storing of mutli-polygons or multi-points

Comment: I am thinking of quering those specific tables without doctrine mapping. It may be easier and more flexible...